# How to implement stopping criteria Taylor series?

Tags: c, taylor-series

I was writing a C program to calculate `e^x` and to stop when the system satisfies the relation `x^k/k!<t/e` where t is a fixed tolerance.
I don't know how to implement this last condition, because in the code, the value of `k` should not be known and it always gives me wrong results.
This is the code I wrote when k is known; how can I modify this?

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int factorial(int);
double tolerace();

int main() {

    int n;

    double x, k;
    double value, ex;

    value = ex = 0.0;

    printf("Enter the value for x and n");
    scanf("%lf %d", & x, & n);

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        value = pow(x, k);
        ex = ex + value / factorial(k);
    }
    ex = ex + 1;
    printf("Result  %lf", ex);

    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n) {
    int j, fact = 1;

    for (j = n; j > 0; j--)
        fact = fact * j;
    return fact;
}

double tolerace() {
    double t, m;
    m = pow(10, (-4));
    do {
        printf("\n range of tolerance 0<t<= 10^-4: ");
        scanf("%lf", & t);
    }
    while (t < 0 || t > m);
    return t;
}
```

I have tried defining the value of e and creating a while loop but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You don't call `tolerance()`, which is arguably misspelled ('tolerance' has an n in it; your declaration and definition are self-consistent but omit the n).

Comment: Look at the change between consecutive terms, say with `if(fabs(prev_term - this_term) < epsilon) break;`

Answer (score 2):

The x<sup>k</sup> / k! in your condition is the current term in your series. You don't know what your e is yet, because you are calculating it, so you must estimate it with the sum of the terms so far.

```
double x = 1.0;
double e = 1.0;

double t = 1.0e-8;

int k;

for (k = 1; ; k++) {
    double a = pow(x, k) / fact(k);
    
    e += a;
    if (e * a < t) break;
}
```

Here, a decreases with every term, so that the series converges and eventually the termination criterion is met. (If x is −1, the criterion will be satisfied immediately, because the accumulated e is 0. Your program should probably treat negative values with the relation e(−x) = 1 / e(x).)

There's a problem, though: The terms decrease rapidly, because the factorials grow fast. With 32-bit ints, you can represent up to 12!, wit 64-bit ints up to 20!. Depending on your tolerance, you may need higher factorials. It's also inefficient to re-calculate the factorials from the beginning every time.

The usual approach with such series is to represent a<sub>k</sub> in terms of the previous term a<sub>k − 1</sub>. The series is:

e<sup>x</sup> ≈ 1   +   x / 1   +   x·x / 1 ·2   +   x·x·x / 1·2·3   +   x·x·x·x· / 1·2·3·4   +   ...

So:

a<sub>k</sub> = a<sub>k − 1</sub> · x / k

Your program could now be:

```
double x = 1.0;
double e = 1.0;
double a = 1.0;

double t = 1.0e-8;

int k;
for (k = 1; ; k++) {
    a *= x / k;
    
    e += a;
    if (e * a < t) break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help , the code now is ok , thanks for the detailed explanation ;)